# can't storing and retrieving images and files into database in spring mvc with MyEclipse IDE

Tags: spring-mvc

I m doing a real time project using spring mvc with MyEclipse IDE without integrating maven, and my question is how to store and retrieve images and files into database.

Answer (score 0):

Controller code for storing an image file in a database:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveproduct")    
public ModelAndView add(@ModelAttribute("command") CommonBean cbean,
          BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    CommonsMultipartFile file = cbean.getImage();       
    System.out.println("file content is " + file);
    cbean.setFile(file.getBytes());
    ProductModel model = new ProductModel();
    try {
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(model, cbean);
        eworldservice.addproduct(model);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ModelAndView("home");
}
```